# NSArray return specific values

Tags: ios

```
NSArray *arr = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"m", 
                    @"f", 
                    @"m", 
                    @"f", 
                    @"f", 
                    nil];
```

How can I put all the values of `@"f"` into it's own array simply? Using a *key-value collection operator* (not using manual loop)?

eg I would think it might look like `[arr valueForKeyPath:@"self==f"]`. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an NSPredicate:

```
[arr filteredArrayUsingPredicate:
 [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"self == %@", @"f"]];
```

Answer (score 1):

Key-value collection operators are built for aggregate operations (e.g. **count**, **sum**, **min**, **max**) and not filtering. There's no way to do this using these operators, but you could use `[NSArray indexesOfObjectsPassingTest:]` and `[NSArray objectsAtIndexes:]` (or just `[NSArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:]`) to achieve the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

```
This is your Array
NSArray *arr = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"m", @"f", @"m", @"f", @"f", nil];

in normal functionality is

NSArray *FinalArray = [NSArray alloc]init];
for(int i=0;i <[arr count];i++)
{
 if([arr objectAtIndex:i] isEqualAtString:@"f"])
{
  [FinalArray addObject:[arr objectAtIndex:i]];
}
}
```